# What is the most efficient way to override Bootstrap css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, opencart

I'm using Opencart for a E-Commerce site for my company.  The Opencart developer is working on V2.0 which will incorporate Bootstrap as the default styling.

My plan was to put a link in my header file on the next line BELOW the link to bootstrap stylesheet example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/override.css" />
```

I was planning on using LESS to compile into override.css and only change small parts of the Bootstrap less to meet my needs.   For example, I was planning on only including the variables.less from bootstrap along with buttons.less and layout.less.  I'd then compile those modified files into override.css to get my personalized styles. However, the more I think about it, I realize I'd need to include all the LESS from Bootstrap. This would make my override.css essentially the same as bootstrap.css (with the exception of the changes I make for my styling).

This essentially defeats the purpose of having an override.  Is there a way to not need to include ALL the bootstrap less, just the parts that I want in the override?

People may be wondering why I don't just modify the bootstrap.css file.  My thought is that if  I do modify the bootstrap.css file all my changes will be overwritten if I go to upgrade (or if the Opencart developer upgrades) bootstrap in the future.

Any advise is much appreciated!

Thanks!

DS-MATT

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep an `overwrite.css` to yourself, while presenting compiled `bootstrap.css` + `override.css` to the end user? That way you can easily update your `bootstrap.css` in the future and easily maintain the overrides themselves.

Comment: Hi RR - If I do this I lose the benefits of variables in less.  Example, if I want to change the colors of the site buttons, text, links, etc. I'd have to search through the CSS and find and replace every instance of that in the new CSS file.  This also seems redundant and inefficient.

Comment: That's why you keep the `override.css`, so you won't have to. All you would need to do is to recompile the files and upload them to production server.